# I can't get access to my iPhone 4s on Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, sync, iphone, ios

Running the command lsusb shows Bus 001 Device 012: ID 05ac:12a0 Apple, Inc. iPhone 4S
, I can use it as a 3g hotspot through usb,and of course it can charge it. I have tried reinstalling libimobiledevice4 and using ifuse to mount it or something; but, still nothing shows up on Dolphin or any other application. How can I access files on my iPhone and sync music? I used to be able to access the phone on Ubuntu 14.10 and every thing worked fine.